# In the New Testament, why is Jesus called Jesus, but Joshua is still called Joshua?

Tags: jesus, new-testament, joshua

I know that Jesus is the transliteration of the Greek word for Joshua.  Totally get that.

Here's the question -- in Acts (and other places), another person named Joshua is mentioned, but he is actually called "Joshua".  Why is that?